# Angular.element('#id'), angular.element(document.queryselector('#id') alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there an alternative for `Angular.element('#id'), angular.element(document.queryselector('#id')` that returns ALL the elements with the same id / class in angular?

Comment: all elements with same id ? **id must be Unique** use class for it

Comment: id or class.. doesn't matter :3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get multiple element references matching a selector

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.x'))
```

Note: [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) of an element must be unique, so use it only for class for any selectors

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cd8xj693/1/)

Comment: No need to use `document.querySelectorAll`, `angular.element` is an alias for jQuery

Comment: @Maximus no.. the jQuery lite version does not support selectors

Comment: @ArunPJohny, ah, I see, thanks, I've always been using it with jQuery

Comment: @Maximus http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cd8xj693/2/ - `Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element`

Comment: @downvoter did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

Angular.element only works if the full version of jQuery is available:

"If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."
See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

If not you'll get the error that [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) mentioned.

To get the unique element with "#id" or the first element with "#id" if there is more than one (all subsequent elements with "#id" will be ignored) you can use document.querySelector('#id').

If you want to get more than one element you'll have to use a class using document.querySelectorAll('.class').

Answer (score 1):

You should check your design. **IDs have to be unique** inside one document.

If you need to access multiple Elements of the same type use a class instead.

You can access these elements by "Angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.className') afterwards

Comment: Thanks, i know that, i just had some toggle on/off things with same ID. a div that had the same id but only 1 is shown. Im just testing things out right now.

Comment: It just is more than "just a paradigm". Functions just don't report arrays if you access IDs

Comment: Oh, that i didn't know.